# Diophantine equation $2y^4-2y^2 +1=z^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

How to solve the diophantine equation $2y^4-2y^2 +1=z^2$, where $(y,z) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ ?

Thanks,

W

Comment: Well, looks like I can get it in the form $(2y^2-1)^2=2z^2-1$.  Not sure if that helps.  I'm retagging this for diophantine equations.

Comment: $(y^2)^2+(y^2-1)^2=z^2$, One solution y=2, z=5

Comment: If you then let $x = y^2$, we have $x^2 + (x-1)^2 = z^2$: the solutions to this are *leg-leg twin Pythagorean triples*.

Comment: Using the expression of @labbhattacharjee and the general solutions of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple hopefully will help.
See also the comment of Théophile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the quartic has the rational solution $y=0,x=1$, it is birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve.

We find the curve to be $j^2=k^3+4k^2-4k$ with $y=2k/j$ and $x=k(k^2+4)/j^2$.

The curve has one finite torsion point $(0,0)$, and Denis Simon's ellrank package gives the rank to be 1 with generator $G=(2,4)$. Thus there are an infinite number of RATIONAL solutions to the equation.

For example, $5G$ gives $y=187/23$ and $x=49081/529$.

Increasing the multiples of $G$ gives rational solutions with larger and larger sizes of the numerator and denominator.

For natural numbers, $(y,x)= (0,  1), ( 1, 1), ( 2,  5)$ SEEM
to be the only solutions. I would be very surprised if higher multiples of $G$ give
an integer solution, but this is not a proof.

Hope I have this all correct!!

Allan MacLeod

Comment: Sir is there any elementary solution??